# Wrong pojo returned to baking bean JSF

Tags: jsf

I'm making simple app using JSF.
Here's my simple form for adding items in to database:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="product" required="true" type="dk.xakeps.web.models.Product"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <c:set value="#{cc.attrs.product.localizedProducts[facesContext.viewRoot.locale]}" var="localizedProduct"/>
    <b:form id="modalForm">
        <b:label for="title" value="#{msg['product.edit.title']}"/>
        <b:inputText id="title" value="#{localizedProduct.title}"/>
        <b:label for="description" value="#{msg['product.edit.description']}"/>
        <b:inputTextarea id="description" value="#{localizedProduct.description}"/>
        <b:label for="price" value="#{msg['product.edit.price']}"/>
        <b:message for="price"/>
        <b:inputText id="price" value="#{localizedProduct.price}"/>
        <b:commandButton action="#{productBean.saveProduct(cc.attrs.product, localizedProduct)}" value="#{msg['product.save']}"/>
    </b:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

Wrong `localizedProduct` passed to `productBean.saveProduct`, passed instance is not null, but empty.

Here's how i'm getting `Product` instance inside template:

```
<c:set value="#{productBean.getNewProduct()}" var="product"/>
<b:modal styleClass="addModal">
    <custom:editProduct product="${product}"/>
</b:modal>
```

`LocalizedProduct` has 4 fields: title, description, price and locale. Only locale isn't null, other fields are null. On form submit, `LocalizedProduct` is filled, but `saveProduct` called with empty instance.

[LocalizedProduct.java](https://pastebin.com/rbaRe3zH)

[Product.java](https://pastebin.com/jaZaZ3k9)

[ProductBean.java](https://pastebin.com/ME8TpSwM)